# Android studio doesn't recognize Zenfone2

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I work on OSX.

Android Studio couldn't see Zenfone2 via USB.

According to the guidelines from the others,
My phone already turned on developer mode and USB debugging.
I also tried switching from  MTP to PTP to MTP mode and it didn't work as well.

(However, both XiaomiRed6 and SamsungS8 are recognized)

Any clues?

Comment: Dunno, try downloading some drivers from the manufacturers website.

Comment: Are there only drivers for Windows?  It said that OSX doesn't need drivers.

Comment: Contact Asus support and explain the situation to them.